# My name is Abram, yet I will not beget a son

Tags: riddle

My name is Abram.

I will not beget a son named Isaac. I will not know the joy of creating a people. As I roam the desert, I bring only death. I will never become Abraham. In fact, I'm not even human!

Why is this?

Comment: Surely the _huge majority_ of people called Abram are not the biblical character of that name. This seems like a bit of a non-riddle to me. (Also, it's mothers who conceive; fathers beget.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I made the word mistake because I'm not an English native speaker. Also, added a bit of extra info. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Is it possible that you are

> an [M1 Abrams tank](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/M1_Abrams)? These certainly roam the desert bringing death. I'm a bit concerned about "Abram" versus "Abrams", though.

Answer (score 1):

You are the

> M1 Abrams tank.
>  It's used in desert combat, it brings destruction and being a tank, it isn't human, so can't create people.